# .project files, .settings folders, bin folders keep auto generating in VSCode after an accidental IntelliJ Maven import

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

After trying to import an existing project made from scratch with Maven pom files and a single .project file from working with a diagram in Eclipse into IntelliJ a whole bunch of .settings folders, bin directories (src, target, pom), and .project files with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>xyz</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Note that before I did the import I did have a single .project file in one of my directories, from working with a diagram in Eclipse.

Any idea what happened? And why VSCode is continuously auto generating all of this random stuff ever since the IntelliJ import.

I am used to just having my Pom files throughout.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently this problem is generated by extensions related to the java language.
I solved this by removing the java extensions.

According to similarities that can be seen in this [open issue](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/634):

https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/634

Comment: Kind of pathetic that this is still true.  Thanks for the info.